# Can one have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n10^{k-n}(-a)^{k-1}= 0$ for some $\lvert a \rvert > 1/10$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I've used the geometric series formula to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} 10^{k-n}(-a)^{k-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[10^{1-n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-10a)^{k-1}\Big]=\Big(\lim_{n\to\infty}10^{1-n}\Big)\frac{1}{1+10a}
$$
for $\mid{a}\mid<\frac{1}{10}$ which evaluates to zero due to the $10^{1-n}$ term, but I was wondering if there's a way to prove this for some larger $\mid{a}\mid$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} 10^{k-n}(-a)^{k-1}&=\Big[10^{1-n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-10a)^{k-1}\Big]
\\&= \Big[10^{1-n} \frac{(1-(-10a)^n)}{1-(-10a)}\Big]
\\&=\frac{10}{1+10a}  \left(\frac{1}{10^n}- (-a)^n \right)
\end{align}

In particular, I can choose $a= 0.5$ and we can see that as $n \to \infty$,  the sum converges to $0$.

Comment: A good example where suppressing all four occurrences of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ would only make the proof more easily readable... (+1)

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: Thus the limit exists for every $$|a|<1$$since the singularity at $a=-\frac1{10}$ is only apparent.